# Unable to create a table in AWS-mysql and it throw Error code 1044. Access denied for user 'user1'@'%' to database 'mysqlDB'

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have Mysql Db created in aws-rds. Iam trying to create a table for my DB with below code

```
create table employee (
id int, name varchar(10),
place varchar(10)
);
```

but while executing the script, **it throw Error code 1044. Access denied for user 'user1'@'%' to database 'mysqlDB'**. I gone through different solution and tried by giving permission/privilege to the user and even i changed the password as suggested in the Developer form. But nothing seems to be working fine

Can anyone help on this?
Thank you

Comment: Not clear if you yourself created the database? I get this on DB create.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database first then a table.
Try something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE employees;

CREATE TABLE employee (
id int, name varchar(10),
place varchar(10)
);
```